# What is the best way to organize a .net core app with nginx reverse proxy inside a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, kubernetes

I want to deploy a .NET Core app with NGINX reverse proxy on Azure Kubernetes Service. What is the best way to organize the pods and containers?

1. Two single-container pods, one pod for nginx and one pod for the app (.net-core/kestrel), so each one can scale independently of the other
2. One multi-container pod, this single pod with two containers (one for nginx and one for the app)
3. One single-container pod, a single container running both the nginx and the .net app

I would choose the 1st option, but I don't know if it is the right choice, would be great to know the the pros and cons of each option.

If I choose the 1st option, is it best to set affinity to put nginx pod in the same node that the app pod? Or anti-affinity so they deploy on different nodes? Or no affinity/anti-affinity at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice for inbound traffic in Kubernetes is to use the [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource. This requires a bit of extra setup in AKS because there's no built-in ingress controller. You definitely don't want to do #2 because it's not flexible, and #3 is not possible to my knowledge.

The Kubernetes `Ingress` resource is a configuration file that manages reverse proxy rules for inbound cluster traffic. This allows you to surface multiple services as if they were a combined API.

To set up ingress, start by creating a public IP address in your auto-generated MC resource group:

```
az network public-ip create `
    -g MC_rg-name_cluster-name_centralus `
    -n cluster-name-ingress-ip `
    -l centralus `
    --allocation-method static `
    --dns-name cluster-name-ingress
```

Now create an ingress controller. This is required to actually handle the inbound traffic from your public IP. It sits and listens to the Kubernetes API `Ingress` updates, and auto-generates an `nginx.conf` file.

```
# Note: you'll have to install Helm and its service account prior to running this. See my GitHub link below for more information
helm install stable/nginx-ingress `
    --name nginx-ingress `
    --namespace default `
    --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=ip.from.above.result `
    --set controller.scope.enabled=true `
    --set controller.scope.namespace="default" `
    --set controller.replicaCount=3

kubectl get service nginx-ingress-controller -n default -w
```

Once that's provisioned, make sure to use this annotation on your `Ingress` resource: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`

If you'd like more information on how to set this up, please see [this GitHub readme](https://github.com/brbarnett/hello-k8s) I put together this week. I've also included TLS termination with `cert-manager`, also installed with Helm.

Comment: But I would need to use nginx-ingress to route between all services plus a nginx for my .net app plus my app. Two layers of nginx or the nginx-ingress will route requests direct to my .ney app?

Comment: Nginx is for ingress only in this specific case. Once your traffic is within your app, you can refer to other apps in your cluster via service name. No additional nginx required

Comment: My app use a .net core built-in kestrel server that doesn't have enough web-server features, like gzip compression, ssl and request logs. It is common to use nginx in front of kestrel as a reverse proxy, routing requests to a not-exposed kestrel. Should I do all these things (compression, https, request logs, etc...) in the nginx/ingress or is it best to have another nginx in front of my app to handle these things isolated from all the other things that the nginx-ingress already does?

Comment: what do you suggest? @brandon-barnett

Comment: The job of the ingress controller is to terminate TLS and route traffic within your cluster. Giving it the additional jobs you've suggested gives it too many application-specific concerns, especially when you start to build more applications around it. My suggestion would be to create the flow of cloud LB (this auto-provisions with the `nginx-ingress` installation) > `nginx-ingress` > internal nginx/HAProxy/Envoy/Varnish load balancer (w/ additional features enabled) > .NET Core app

Comment: this has answered my specific doubt, thank you!. Last question, so the internal nginx would be as a sidecar of the app, so if I have three instances of the app, then each would have its own internal nginx. that is ok right?